# Getting 404 when trying to access OneNote files in a folder within Angular App

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function within a service that is suppose to look at onenote files and return a list of files that match search terms (hard coded at the moment). It keeps giving me 404 not found in the Get request and cannot find the OneNoteFiles folder. Here is the exact error in the browser console:
"Get http://localhost:4200/OneNoteFiles 404 (Not Found)"

I created a folder at the root called OneNoteFiles and use the below function in the data services-

```
 searchOneNote() {
    const searchResults: string[] = [];
    const searchKeyword = 'Problem';
    const searchFiles = {dir: string) =. {
        this.http.get(dir).subscribe((data: any) => {
            for(let file of data) {
                this.http.get(file, {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe((fileData: any) => {
                    const regex = new RegExp(searchKeyword, 'gi')
                    if(regex.test(fileData)) {
                        searchResults.push(file);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    const folderPath = './OneNoteFiles';
    searchFiles(folderPath);
    return searchResults;
 
 }
 }
```

The OneNoteFiles folder is in the root of the application.  The path to the service is src/app/services if that matters.  However I keep getting a 404 not found in the Get request.  Any idea as to why?

I have checked file permissions and the path appears correct.

Comment: so you don't have any local server that handles `/OneNoteFiles` route then how you want data to be returned to client side?